# Long and short memory in reinforcement learning Connect 4 AI

Tags: neural-networks, python, game-theory, reinforcement-learning, board-games

I'm writing an AI based on reinforcement learning to play Connect 4. That's my second bot and attempt to RNN and AI (first was copy a code of snake RNN AI from youtube) and I'm looking for some advices and also I have a question.

In [mentioned video](https://youtu.be/6pJBPPrDO40?t=823) there are to functions `train_short_memory` and `train_long_memory`. `train_short_memory` is called after every move (that function as I understand updates weights in NN).
`train_long_memory` is called every time the game ends and in that function we take all the data we obtained so far and do the same as `train_short_memory` (updates weights right?)

In Connect 4 it's a bit more tricky, because I think I should remember every move (as `train_short_memory`) and then after the game ends I should record the whole "path" of the game, save it and also update rewards (if my moves were scored +2, +5, -3, +2, +5, but at the end I won, I add to all of them +10 points for example). On a given path (list of states which I used in `train_short_memory`) I should use a function, let's call it `train_long_memory` (which is `train_long_memory` but not on the whole memory, but only on the states of the last game), that will again update weights.
Should I also call `train_long_memory` on all saved states (`n` games) as in video of Snake? If so when should I call it? right now I'm calling it every time my AI makes a record of wins in a row, but because the winratio is ~85% against random bot, it will not appear often. Maybe should I call it every 10 wins in row (it can get up to 60 wins in row, but the average number is around 20)?

Do you have any experience in two player game in turns? how do you store states and when do you store it?